# Select primary display in xorg.conf

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, amd-graphics-card

I'm running kubuntu with ATI video card and fglrx driver. I have three monitor setup with two monitors that shows up like a projector(2,3) on the left and the right as a normal lcd (1). I want the one on the right as my main monitor(1) with the menu toolbar. Currently the menu tool bar is going across the other two monitors(2,3).

```
************************************************
*              *               *               *
*       3      *       2       *       1       *
*              *               *****************
************************************************
```

Anybody know how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the proprietary ATI config utility.

You already say you're using the fglrx driver. Thus you can probably just go under Administration > ATI Config (something close to that). It may also be named something like "Catalyst".

You can also go to [here and download](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/drivers.aspx) the latest version (though if the version that's in apt is working for you, then I'd suggest you stick with that).

The 'Monitor' GUI in Ubuntu may work for you too. It requires some X11 extension I usually don't run though, so that may not work for you as well.

Hope that points ya in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the propitiatory driver and use the open source one (radeon). Then use the "Configure Display" tool.